# Running Open Cover on a WCF service (without stopping the service)

Tags: wcf, opencover

Currently I am using the following to run my OpenCover on my service layer,

net stop w3svc /y

OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe -target:C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe -targetargs:-debug -targetdir:B2.4.9\Application\Sample.Web.WCF\bin -filter:+[*]* -register:user -output:opencoverSvcResult.xml

net start w3svc

Is it possible to run the OpenCover on a service layer, WITHOUT stopping the service, as I would like to run these tests on a server machine, which is shared by other applications.

Thanks,
Bobin Cheiran

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the answer is no. :(

OpenCover needs to instrument your modules and this cannot be currently done by using the attach functionality that is available to profilers like OpenCover.

You could possibly use IISEXPRESS to host your web application or some other self-hosting mechanism and this would give you more control over stopping and starting your application without affecting other users.